# How to use % in oracle for calculation

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have defined a logic where I want to use `%` percentage as a calculation but its giving me error while using.

Below is the logic.

```
ELSIF V_ANCHOR_NONANCHOR = 'Anchor'
THEN
v_STD_REVISED_AMT := (V_STANDRD_AMT  - v_OD_Discount) - ((V_STANDRD_AMT  - v_OD_Discount * 10%));
```

and the error is

> Error(103,94): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "%" when expecting one of the following:     ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec as between || member submultiset The symbol "%" was ignored.

Please suggest how to use it.

**update**

`v_STD_REVISED_AMT := (V_STANDRD_AMT  - v_OD_Discount) - ((V_STANDRD_AMT  - v_OD_Discount * 0.1), (V_STANDRD_AMT  - v_OD_Discount));`

giving error as

> Error(108,22): PLS-00412: list of values not allowed as argument to this function or procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want the multiplication by `0.1` which is `10/100` means `10%` as follows:

```
(V_STANDRD_AMT  - (v_OD_Discount * 0.1))
```

**-- Update**

The entire solution should be as follows:

```
v_STD_REVISED_AMT := (V_STANDRD_AMT  - v_OD_Discount) 
                     - CASE WHEN V_ANCHOR_NONANCHOR = 'Anchor' 
                              OR (M2_DATE_COL_VARIABLE < DATE '2019-03-31' 
                                  AND M2_DATE_COL_VARIABLE > DATE '2016-07-13') 
                            THEN (V_STANDRD_AMT  - v_OD_Discount * 10%)  
                            ELSE 0 
                       END;
```

Comment: I am 100% sure.

Comment: why you have `,` in this expression?

Comment: Can you please explain to me what is the logic that you want to achieve using this entire line?

Comment: how will I use `(BJ2*2.5)%`